# Microsoft graph api throws The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise while creating event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to create meeting event. I have added user in azure ad and also assigned delegated permission Calendars.ReadWrite.

But while creating event by following lines it throws error:

```
var response = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

Code: MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI
Message: The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.

Comment: According to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request) and your error message, I think you should check if you have a default calendar first by calling  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars`

Comment: @TinyWang Same is working fine if I allow Microsoft 365 developer license to this user from 365 admin portal.

Comment: Then the issue solved right? Congratulations : )

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, but why it is not working with Azure AD. There was some answer regarding this is I need those Azure Ad users on online exchange.

Comment: `Microsoft 365 developer license` maybe the result. In my opinion, your users may don't have a licence for them to using Calendar, so we can't create event for them.

Answer (score 1):

Here I found answer from Microsoft :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/761931/microsoft-graph-api-throws-the-mailbox-is-either-i.html

Answer (score 0):

I had an incorrect clientId/Secret/tenant combination